# iPhone iOS5 Storyboard change navbar appearance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard

I want my navbars to use black transparent appearance. In my non-storyboard apps, i could put this code in the `AppDidFinishLoadingWithOptions` :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[AppColors navBarColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setAlpha:0.7];

[[[UITableView appearance] backgroundView]setBackgroundColor:[AppColors tableViewBackgroundColor]];
[[[UITableViewCell appearance] backgroundView]setBackgroundColor:[AppColors tableViewCellBackgroundColor]];
```

Where would this code go if I'm using a storyboard? It appears that my controllers are loaded before the app finishes launching

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will continue to work with storyboards. The `appearance` class method returns a proxy object that defines style information for all created instances of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in the `viewDidLoad` method in your applications root view controller.